# How to use the value of array inside DB raw Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I have question about DB raw in Laravel. Actually now I have a variable named `$currencies` with the structure like this.

```php
<?php

$currencies = [
    'CNY' => 1000,
    'USD' => 10000
]
```

And I need to use the value of that array for sorting my products table. With the `products` table looks like this:

```
| id  |  product_name  | original_currency  | price |
|  1  | lorem ipsum d  | CNY                | 20    |
|  2  | new product n  | USD                | 10    |
```

So far my code looks like this:

```php
$products = DB::raw(SELECT product_name, 
                           price, 
                           price * $currencies[original_currency] AS converted_price 
                    FROM products);
```

But I got the error `Undefined Index: original_currency`

I just need to access the correct value to set the `converted_price`. So the expected result will looks like this:

```
| id  |  product_name  | original_currency  | price |  converted_price  |
|  1  | lorem ipsum d  | CNY                | 20    |  20000            |
|  2  | new product n  | USD                | 10    |  1000000          |
```

Comment: That's not even valid php code. There are no `'` or `"` surrounding the query.

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

- Pass query as a string, missing single or double quotes around the query.
- You can't directly use PHP array inside queries, because queries are being sent to MySQL server and that doesn't have access to your PHP variables.

Solutions:

Approach 1: Fetch simple data from MySQL, modify data in PHP

```
    $products = DB::raw('SELECT products.product_id, products.original_currency, products.price FROM products);

    foreach($products as $key => $value) {
        $value['converted_price'] = $value['price'] * $currencies[$value['original_currency']];
    }
```

Approach 2: Use Temp table in MySQL:

```
    SELECT 
        products.product_id,
        products.price,
        products.price * weight_table.weight AS converted_price
    FROM products
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 'CNY' AS currency, 100 AS weight
        UNION
        SELECT 'USD' AS currency, 1000 AS weight
    ) AS weight_table 
        ON products.original_currency = weight_table.currency;
```

If you have dynamic currency array in PHP, use the following code to generate inner temp table.

```
$currencies = [
    'CNY' => 100,
    'USD' => 1000
];

function getTempTable($arrCurrency) {
    $arrQuery = [];
    foreach($arrCurrency as $key => $value) {
        $arrQuery[] = "SELECT '" . $key . "' AS currency, " . $value . " AS weight";
    }

    return implode(PHP_EOL. " UNION " . PHP_EOL, $arrQuery); 
}

$strQuery = 'SELECT 
    products.product_id,
    products.price,
    products.price * weight_table.weight AS converted_price
FROM products
INNER JOIN ( ' . getTempTable($currencies) . ') AS weight_table
    ON products.original_currency = weight_table.currency';

$products = DB::raw($strQuery);
```

Comment: The solution looks fine, but this could potentially be simplified using a macro on the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class.